# Elements/Wired Style 3D Animation

Tags: iphone, animation, 3d, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to implement the style of 3D rotational animation you see in the Elements and the Wired iPad applications. The animation has the UIScrollView style acceleration so it looks like they have connected a UIScrollView to a sequence of images.

I have tried implementing it in UIKit, using an "empty" UIScrollView to increment through an array of images and set the contents of a UIImageView, based on the content offset. This works but even with scaled down images on the simulator, it is very sluggish. I am not sure how I could optimise it to make it run faster.

[Source Code on GitHub](http://github.com/smendrick/ScrollViewAnimate)

I have also tried doing something similar in Cocos2D. Cocos could animate the sequence very smoothly but I couldn't control the animation. I tried using a scroll view and setDisplayFrame to step through an animation but it didn't work.

Any help or suggestions on either option would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not knowing uiscrollview might be MacOS or Carbon or whatever specific, it would help if there was maybe one more tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the effect you're trying to achieve, but if you're referring to the images in "The Elements" app which you can spin around, then yeah, you probably don't want to be doing that with an UIScrollView.

You can control the animation of content in Cocos2d.  While you can set an animation to "just run", you can also manually set frames directly out of an animation, so if you can get smooth animation out of Cocos, you should be able to do it interactively.  Look at the atlas sprite object - you can set the rect of an animation frame directly.

However, again, I'm not sure this is the best approach, either, since that's a lot of frames for a texture.  If you're going to be doing a lot of 3D photographic objects, you might consider looking into the video codecs and scrubbing along a video instead of trying to pack all the frames of a rotation animation into a series of textures.

Just so you know, the guy who made "The Elements" wrote [an article about the development of the app](http://www.popsci.com/gadgets/article/2010-04/exclusive-making-elements-one-ipads-most-magical-apps), and here's what he had to say about the 3D rotatable objects:

> "Creating fluidly spinning objects with the level of crystal clear photographic quality I demanded is actually harder than it might seem. A number of the obvious things the more technical of you might think of turn out not to work for reasons too complicated to get into here. Suffice to say that John designed a brilliant solution that uses the iPad's excellent graphics subsystem to lend a hand in ways it's not normally intended to."

I don't know how exactly they achieved the 3D objects, but perhaps that "uses the iPad's excellent graphics subsystem" mention gives you a clue where to head from here...

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article.